# ZF2 view rendering in another view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I don't want to add child to the viewModel in action controller:

```
// action controller
public function indexAction() {
    $result = new ViewModel();
    $result->setTemplate('application/view/another-action');

    $comments = new ViewModel();
    $comments->setTemplate('application/view/child-comments');
    $result->addChild($comments, 'child_comments');

    return $result;
}
...
// View
<div>
<?php echo $this->child_comments ?>
</div>
```

I want to include view in another view:

```
<div>
  <?php
  $view = new ViewModel();
  $view->setVariables($this->var);
  $view->setTemplate('page_nav.phtml');
  // here I want to render view 
  ?>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [`Partial`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.4/library/Zend/View/Helper/Partial.php) view helper does (docs seem to be outdated, but I'll link them anyway [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper)):

```php
<div>
    <?php echo $this->partial('page_nav', array('var' => $this->var)) ?>
<div>
```

Obviously, your `page_nav` should be known by your view resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can also simply call `$this->render('path/to/view-script')`